# MySQL order by field(column_name, subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get data in order to display something like this:

db schema:

| category_id | parent_category |
| --- | --- |
| banana | fruit |
| apple | fruit |
| kiwi | fruit |
| cucumber | vegetable |
| celery | vegetable |
| pork | meat |
| beef | meat |
| chicken | meat |
| t-shirt | clothes |
| jeans | clothes |
| sweater | clothes |
| meat | food |
| fruit | food |
| vegetable | food |
| food | null |
| clothes | null |

```
select * from category 
order by 
field(category_id, "banana") desc,
field(parent_category, (SELECT parent_category FROM category WHERE category_id = "banana")) desc
field(category_id, (select category_id from category where parent_category <> (SELECT parent_category FROM category WHERE category_id = "banana"))) desc
```

my goal result is to display with following order:
banana first,
other kinds of fruits second,
other kinds of food third,
clothes last (all other data that are not considered as food.)
second and third level categories don't have to be displayed (meat, fruit, vegetable, t-shirt, jeans, sweater, food, clothes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM category 
 WHERE 
    IF(parent_category='food',NULL,parent_category) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN category_id='banana' THEN 1
        WHEN parent_category='fruit' THEN 2
        WHEN parent_category='clothes' THEN 99
        ELSE 3 END;
```

Using `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` section and filter out `parent_category` that is `food` and `NULL`. Result will be like this:

| category_id | parent_category |
| --- | --- |
| banana | fruit |
| apple | fruit |
| kiwi | fruit |
| cucumber | vegetable |
| celery | vegetable |
| pork | meat |
| beef | meat |
| chicken | meat |
| t-shirt | clothes |
| jeans | clothes |
| sweater | clothes |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bff481fb9bd5c7d9e4ece553bd83f3ec)